# selected object not updating in object array (between components) for angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, components, mat-stepper

i have a parent component (name steps, i use material-step) and this parent component's have 2 child component.

This child components using same model:

[image]

i push data in the listing model with many functions. Later, i want to update the selected index in the step-2 but not update. Update was success on the change function but later it's getting back to its old self.

i try too many methods for update object in object array but can do nothing.

parent-component:

[image]

step-1:

[image]

step-2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the parent component to update listingModel as per the changes you make in one of the children components, you need to use two-way data binding (that is, @Input and @Output).

Once you do that, Angular should be smart enough to propagate the changes from the parent to the other child, because you are already using data binding.

Comment: hi, thanks for comment, i tried change data on the parent component. data changed in the change function but it's getting back to its old self after the function is finished.

Comment: thanks for helping, i fixed and I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

i made progress:

[image]

if i click the masterToggle, updating success on the next step.
But if i click singular row (running the checkBoxLabel func.), updating not working on the next step.

this functions in the mat-table

note: filterEmptyMerge -> pushing the my listing model for selected rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

***I fixed this problem.***

firstly, i use equal map for selected items. As a result; if other component want to update for inside the selected items, update not working.

> this.listing.merges = this.selection.selected.map((select) => select);

I change equalt map process as a just push selected items and fixed.

> this.selection.selected.map((select) => { this.listing.merges.push(select); });

But singular select didn't work. I realized that mat-table use own toggle method. I change this function as my toggle function (my toggle working with push for listing)

and.. fixed.